# Induced D-modules

Tags: d-modules

According to the usual definition, an induced D-module on a complex manifold $X$ is a right D-module of the form $L \otimes_{\mathscr{O}_X} \mathscr{D}_X$, for $L$ a coherent sheaf of $\mathscr{O}_X$-modules. Moreover, Saito writes that "induced D-modules are naturally defined as right D-modules" (in his paper *Induced D-modules and differential complexes*), and one finds similar comments elsewhere.

Why are induced D-modules naturally **right** D-modules? In other words, what is wrong with  considering **left** D-modules of the form $\mathscr{D}_X \otimes_{\mathscr{O}_X} L$ and calling these "induced"?

Comment: I don't know whether thats the reason, but $f_*$ is more naturally defined for right modules and I think $f_*$ commutes with induction for right modules?

Answer (score 5):

The reason is that the de Rham functor for right $D_X$-modules is defined by the tensor product with the structure sheaf $\mathcal O_X$ (not the highest differential forms as in the left $D_X$-module case) over $D_X$. This is closely related to the definition of differential morphisms between $\mathcal O_X$-modules via the tensor product with $\mathcal O_X$ over $D_X$, see (1.2.1) in the paper. Note also that the passage to the associated induced $D$-modules is noted by the inverse of the de Rham functor DR$^{-1}$.